# How does a boss stem cell "improve the Legendary Forge"?

Tags: dead-cells

After beating Dead Cells for the first time, I received a boss cell I could use to increase the difficulty. One of the difficulty effects says:

> Improve the Legendary Forge:
> 100% maximum for rank "+"
> 100% maximum for rank "++"

What does the game mean by "improve the Legendary Forge"? I know the forge can be used to increase the odds of finding enhanced items, but how is that impacted by increasing the difficulty?

[image: Increasing difficulty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the normal difficulty 0 boss cell (BC), the maximum you can upgrade the legendary forge to is 100% items found at rank "+" then 50% of items at rank "++". The BC you got raised the maximum you can upgrade the forge to 100% items at rank "++".

Comment: It's strange they specify the maximum for rank + since it's already 100% on normal mode.

Comment: @Stevoisiak It's probably to avoid confusion, as later you also unlock the ability to upgrade the loots to S rank from the forge.